# How to get absollute path of rct-image-store://0

Tags: ios, react-native

I cropped Image by ImageEditor this way:

```
   ImageEditor.cropImage(
        photo.imageUri,
        cropData,
        (croppedImageURI) => {                
           imageSource = croppedImageURI;    
        },
        (cropError) => {
            console.log("fail");
        }
    );
```

The path of the cropped Image is "rct-image-store://0". This Image is well displayed if use this path in the same Screen. But if I pass this path to other screen:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Tape', { imageSource });
```

Then I get this error:

> JSON value '{
>       uri = "rct-image-store://0"; }' of type NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to an image. Only local files or data URIs are supported.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-image-resizer](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer) for this.You will get path something like this.

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3BA7E152-E21E-4ADD-84A3-8CCCBC7FBFAE/Documents/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3BA7E152-E21E-4ADD-84A3-8CCCBC7FBFAE/Documents/194D4C64-8EA9-4058-9307-BA1316347DA0.jpg

You can pass this image file path to other screen.Here is an example code:

```
import ImageResizer from 'react-native-image-resizer';
const RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

// The output path you can use whatever you want, for sample I am using 
// documentary path.
const outputPath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}`;

// The imageStore path here is "rct-image-store://0" 
ImageResizer.createResizedImage(
    imageStorePath,
    1280,
    720,
    'JPEG',
    25,
    0,
    outputPath,
).then((success) => {
    console.log(success);
    console.log(success.path);
    //If you console success.path then it will give you something like this
    // /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3BA7E152-E21E-4ADD-84A3-8CCCBC7FBFAE
    // /Documents/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3BA7E152-E21E-4ADD-84A3-8CCCBC7FBFAE/Documents/194D4C64-8EA9-4058-9307-BA1316347DA0.jpg
})
```

Comment: ImageResizer doesn't seem to accept rct-image storage urls like this ```rct-image-store://0```

Comment: Indeed, you were right  I didn't define the outputPath. Saving to cache folder doesn't work for some reason (though I don't need it either). Thank you!

Comment: @pritesh, Thank you very much. I surf the google for days and days. You really save my time.